Which RS485 topology is this and will this work?
I have a basic awareness of RS485 protocol but this is the first time I am working with so many devices on the bus which requires a specific placement so here it goes.

Will the following connection using hubs work?
Do I need more termination resistors? or just one in the main distribution box 1 will be enough? (Yes, microcontroller board has 120Ohm resistor)

Additional information
I have total 6 devices in 4 wire RS485 configuration, out of which 3 are physically on right and 3 and on left side. The connection between them is as following.

To avoid running a long stub we decided to have a hub which just extends the 4 wire connections to multiple connectors that allows us to have different harnesses and easy to maintain them later.


I have successfully done '485 designs like you are suggesting.  To get them to work I had to 1) keep the stub length off the main bus to less than ~6" and 2) used source termination resistors at the driver to reduce the edge speed.


Maybe, it depends on things you don't tell, like speed of bus and length of wiring.

No, there must be only two termination resistors on the bus, at both ends of the main bus cable.


Basically you have a star topology, with a hub in the middle, and all devices connect to the hub, and everything connected to the primary hub are stubs.
The RS-485 is not intended to be used with a star topology, it's one of the worst topologies for RS-485 bus.
It might stil work if you design it carefully, but it may be simpler to just run a cable through each device or even loop through your central hub so that the logical bus topology is linear even if the devices are physically connected in a star.
If all cables are short, then your "main" bus would be the one between MCU and only hub, and short stubs will connect between only hub and each device.
But you have multiple hubs - a star network with sub-star networks.

I have decided to go with the daisy chain now, but I am confused by the RS485 4-wire daisy chain wiring diagram. There are a bunch of images with different connections claiming to be the correct one on the internet.
Can you guys please share a rough daisy chain connection?

@ThunderBolMarut Maybe it would be best to ask that as a separate question, while mentioning what different diagrams you are seeing and what confusions you have over them. For all we know, they might all be correct for a given scenario.

The correct topology for multi-drop 485 is a linear bus connection,  with a termination at each end, matching the nominal impedance of the line. Typically twisted pair is in the order of 100 to 120 Ω. This is also known as a daisy chain.
The general idea is that a transmitting transceiver will send two waves out, one in each direction. These waves will pass and be detected by each receiver on the line. Finally the waves will be absorbed in the two termination resistors.
The receiving transceivers have a high input impedance, and do not load the line significantly. Short stubs of wire between bus and transceiver will have low, and so insignificant, capacitance, and so not cause significant reflections at their connection point. The delay along these stubs will be short so that the reflection from the open circuit at the end will be close in time to the incident wave, and not resolved by the receivers. Long stubs of wire will have a high capacitance, and a significant delay to their reflections.
A hub or star point is just 'long wires' connecting to the middle of a linear bus, and so will cause reflections. A bus connected round in a ring will not have 'ends' to connect the termination resistors to.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The words 'short' and 'long' should be interpreted with respect to the bus and transceivers speed and rise times. The slower the bus, the longer the stub lines can be.
You may get away with the topology you have shown, if the speed and rise times are sufficiently slow for the size of the bus.
A 4-wire bus is really two, electrically independent, 2-wire busses, each with its own differential data pair and pair of termination resistors. A 2-wire bus is illustrated above, with all transceivers bidirectional, and software to configure which is the system master. A 4-wire bus has the master transmitter connected to all the slave receivers on one bus, and all the slave transmitters connected to the master receiver on the other. It can achieve higher throughput than the 2-wire bus, at the expense of flexibility.

I have decided to go with the daisy chain now, but I am confused by the RS485 4-wire daisy chain wiring diagram. There are a bunch of images with different connections claiming to be the correct one on the internet.
Can you guys please share a rough daisy chain connection?

@ThunderBolMarut diagram shared
